# How to code an ALL option into a Combo Box

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a combo box on my form with the choice of choosing organization 10, 20, 30....

I have added `ALL` to the combo list box, but am having trouble implementing an all statement in VBA. Below is the case statement I have to get info from organizations 10, 20, 30. How do I get ALL to generate??

```
Case Is = 1
    If cboOrg.ListIndex < 0 Then
        Call msg("Please select your organization!")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    sQ = sQ & " CC LIKE '" & cboOrg.Value & "*'"
    ORGCC = Trim(cboOrg.Value)
```

Comment: Is this MS Access? What do you do with `sQ` before that `Case`, is there some `WHERE` or `AND`?

Comment: yes access. 

Case Is = 1
            sQ = "SELECT * INTO [" & myFile & "] FROM BUD"

Comment: @Edmond: There needs to be a `WHERE`-clause in your query somewhere...

Comment: @Peter its sayin gsyntex error. missing operator.

I think this is my AND statement:
sQ = sQ & " AND FY = " & cboYear.Value & " AND (ACCT >= " & myAcctLo & " AND ACCT <= " & myAcctHi & ")"

Comment: You might like to use 1=1 for All to avoid problems with ANDs and ORs.

Comment: This is a pretty weird approach. Your combo box should have the data in it you need to filter on. Using the ListIndex instead of the actual data returned is why everything gets so convoluted, seems to me. Despite having programmed in Access professionally since 1996 I did not know that a Null combobox returned -1 for the ListIndex. Seems to me you've written your code so it can be run in cases where it oughtn't be run at all, and that you're including in a single subroutine a bunch of code that should be broken down into smaller pieces that are more closely associated with your UI controls.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should only generate the `WHERE`/`AND`-clause, when value is not `"ALL"` (instead of your current assignment):

```
If (cboOrg.Value <> "ALL") Then
    sQ = sQ & " AND CC LIKE '" & cboOrg.Value & "*'"
End If
```

To make it work without changing code before (generating `AND` or `WHERE`), you could try:

```
If (cboOrg.Value <> "ALL") Then
    sQ = sQ & " CC LIKE '" & cboOrg.Value & "*'"
Else
    sQ = sQ & " 1=1"
End If
```

---

Do you really need the `LIKE` (does `CC` only start with the value selected) or would
`WHERE CC = '" & cboOrg.Value & "'"` be sufficient?

Comment: No i dont really need the like

Comment: @Edmond: Then I'd remove it, this will make your code easier to read and could improve performance. What about the rest of my answer?

Comment: sQ = sQ "WHERE CC = '" & cboOrg.Value & "'"

keep geeting syntex error

Comment: sQ = sQ "WHERE CC = '" & cboOrg.Value & "*'"

Comment: Please check my updated answer. If this does not help, please edit your question to provide the code before (generating `sQ`) and the query that is generated.

Answer (score 0):

Private Sub cmdGo_Click()

```
Dim db As Database, rs As Recordset, sQ As String

Dim oXL, oExcel As Object

Set oXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

fPath = "\\firework\mmcfin\123files\Edmond\Lawson Query\Log\"

myTime = Now()

myFile = Environ("UserName") & "-" & Environ("ComputerName") & "-" & Replace(Replace(Replace(Trim(myTime), "/", "-"), " ", "-"), ":", "-")

pTitle = "Lawson Queries"

Set db = CurrentDb

Select Case cboActBud.ListIndex

    Case Is < 0
        Call msg("Please select your query type first: Actual or Budget!")
        Exit Sub

    Case Is = 0
        sQ = "SELECT * INTO [" & myFile & "] FROM ACT"
        toAdd = "WHERE"

    Case Is = 1
        sQ = "SELECT * INTO [" & myFile & "] FROM BUD"

        If cboBucket.ListIndex < 0 Then
            Call msg("Please select your budget bucket!")
            Exit Sub

        Else

            toAdd = "WHERE BUDGET_NBR = " & cboBucket.Value & " AND"

        End If

End Select

myAcctLo = txtACCT1.Value
myAcctHi = txtACCT2.Value

If IsNull(myAcctLo) Or myAcctLo < 1000 Or myAcctLo > 99999 Then

    Call msg("Account number is missing or invalid!")
    Exit Sub

End If

If IsNull(myAcctHi) Then

    myAcctHi = myAcctLo

End If

If myAcctLo > myAcctHi Then

    Call msg("Account range is invalid!")
    Exit Sub

End If

If myAcctLo < 90000 And myAcctHi >= 90000 Then

    Call msg("You can query amounts or units; but, not both at the same time!")
    Exit Sub

End If

Select Case myAcctLo

    Case Is < 90000: sQ = sQ & "AMT " & toAdd
    Case Is >= 90000: sQ = sQ & "UNT " & toAdd

End Select

Select Case cboLevel.ListIndex

    Case Is < 0
        Call msg("Please select your reporting level: Cost Center or Organization!")
        Exit Sub

    Case Is = 0
        If IsNull(txtCC) Then
            Call msg("Please enter your cost center!")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        sQ = sQ & " CC = " & txtCC.Value
        ORGCC = Trim(txtCC.Value)

    Case Is = 1
        If cboOrg.ListIndex < 0 Then
            Call msg("Please select your organization!")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        sQ = sQ & " CC LIKE '" & cboOrg.Value & "*'"
        ORGCC = Trim(cboOrg.Value)

       If (cboOrg.Value <> "All") Then
        sQ = sQ & " CC LIKE '" & cboOrg.Value & "*'"
        Else
        sQ = sQ & " 1=1"
        End If

End Select

If cboYear.ListIndex < 0 Then

    Call msg("Please select an year!")
    Exit Sub

End If

sQ = sQ & " AND FY = " & cboYear.Value & " AND (ACCT >= " & myAcctLo & " AND ACCT <= " & myAcctHi & ")"

DoCmd.Hourglass True

db.Execute sQ

sQ = "INSERT INTO tblLog (UserName, ComputerName, DateAndTime, ORGORCC, ACCT1, ACCT2, BUDGET, FY) VALUES ('" & _
     Environ("UserName") & "','" & Environ("ComputerName") & "',#" & myTime & "#," & ORGCC & "," & myAcctLo & _
     "," & myAcctHi & "," & IIf(cboBucket.ListIndex < 0, 0, Trim(cboBucket.Value)) & "," & Trim(cboYear.Value) & ")"

db.Execute sQ


DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, myFile, fPath & myFile, True

With oXL

    .Visible = True
    .Workbooks.Open (fPath & myFile)

End With

Set oXL = Nothing

DoCmd.Hourglass False

db.Close
```

Comment: Did your query work before? What happens if you call that code? (it would have been better to edit your question instead of posting an answer yourself)

Comment: Yes it did. When I call that code I get an excel spreadsheet with the data from tables. But when I try to add an ALL statement I have syntax errors (missing operator) in query expression 'ALL

Comment: You need to replace your old `sQ = sQ & " CC LIKE '" & cboOrg.Value & "*'"`by my code.

Comment: Note that evnronment variables can be spoofed. Open a command prompt, change an environment variable such as user and then start msaccess.exe from that command prompt.  Review the appropririate envron variable.  Thus API calls are strongly urged.